# initdb: /usr/lib/libssl.so.3: version `OPENSSL_3.0.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libpq.so.5) BlackArch

Tags: linux, postgresql, openssl, arch

I tried to update postgres on BlackArch distribution
Help me please guys!
or is it better to reinstall the system?

I get an error during initialization:

```
su - postgres -c "initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'"                                                                              
initdb: /usr/lib/libssl.so.3: version `OPENSSL_3.0.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libpq.so.5)
```

And then I tried to fix it using pacman and i get error:

```
error: failed to synchronize all databases (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
```

I read in the forum and manually installed the libcrypto .co.3 package from openssl on which I had an error with the libcrypto .co.3 version